# I don't understand the point of the Theme class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

So I was working with Flutter and I needed a custom Widget for a ListView where every widget has its own theme based on some data.

The proper way to do it seems to be something like this:

```dart
class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomWidget({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  final Color data;
  @override
  _CustomWidgetState createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(primaryColor: widget.data),
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

But if I do it like this, what exactly is the advantage of this?
Specifically applying the color in the container? Why can't I just do `color: widget.data`?

Wouldn't it make more sense if things like `TextTheme` automatically applied to every `Text()` decadence of `Theme()`?

Comment: If your color is just a parameter then it's better to just use `color: widget.data `.  Check here for different use cases https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Comment: The link @SamiHaddad posted contains a section `Using a Theme` which says that you have to use `Theme.of(context)` every time, except for some elements like `FloatingActionButton` which does it automatically. Am I wrong to assume this feels a bit inconsistent that some do it automatically but not all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ThemeData` is used to configure a Theme or MaterialApp widget:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

The `primaryColor` value does not affect the color of the `Text` widget, from the [docs](http://The%20background%20color%20for%20major%20parts%20of%20the%20app%20(toolbars,%20tab%20bars,%20etc)):

> The background color for major parts of the app (toolbars, tab bars, etc)

If you want to change the color of the text then you can use the `textTheme` property:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor : Colors.black,
        textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
        primaryColor : Colors.black
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

`primaryColor`: is used for the appbar

`accentColor`: is used to color the foreground

`textTheme`: will change the color of the text and style it

working example:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bba537def9dbfa771400309a4e6415ed

Comment: But what if I now want to add a different theme to just the `Center()` widget and everything below? Whatever I try, the theme will still default to the theme of `MaterialApp()`

Comment: you can override the theme, check the color of "0" https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bba537def9dbfa771400309a4e6415ed

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being dense, but I don't see anything being overridden

Comment: Here its taking the themedata https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bba537def9dbfa771400309a4e6415ed and here it is overriding https://dartpad.dartlang.org/69075f485c48d22d0c368e86317d9434

Comment: @Naomi check the above two links

Comment: So every time you want to deviate from the main theme, I have to call `Theme.of(context)`?

Comment: Yes exactly @Naomi

Comment: Mmh, am I wrong to assume that that feels a bit illogical? You would think that a `Theme()` widget will automatically apply its theme to all it children, else what's the point of it?

Comment: The themedate is applying the theme for everything in the widget.. But if you want to override the theme then you need to add a theme individually to the widget same as I showed you. This is like android native development, you have a styles.xml file that will add theme to the whole app, then if you want to change the color of an individual view you can add a color to it individually